# Why does this sequence of code gets me out of the loop in a ruby program?

Tags: ruby

When I run these three lines in irb it works

```
date="02 Jul 2008, 08:41"
d=Date.strptime(date, "%d %b %Y, %H:%M").iso8601
Time.parse(d).utc.iso8601
output=>"2008-07-01T18:30:00Z"
```

but when used in a loop, which works fine without these lines, the loop discontinues after generating the output for the first step.
the code which generates the date value is getting marked as nil
example code is as following

```
page_doc = page_doc.xpath('//div[@id="page-body"]').first
page_doc.xpath('./div').each do |div|
  author_node=div.xpath('.//p[@class="author"]/strong/a').first
  if author_node == nil
    author = "NA"
  else
    author = author_node.content.chomp.strip.gsub("Gjest:", "")
  end
  author_url_node = div.xpath('.//p[@class="author"]/strong/a/@href').first
  if author_url_node == nil
    author_url = "NA"
  else
    author_url = @site + author_url_node.content.chomp.strip 
  end
  date_node = div.xpath('.//p[@class="author"]').first
  date = SDF::force_ascii(date_node.content.chomp.strip.reverse[0..17].reverse) if date_node

  content = format_description(div.xpath('.//div[@class="content"]'))
end
```

Comment: To me it is not clear how you bind your two code samples? Is the second the loop _without_ the first lines? And where do you place the lines then, with which variables? Or is the SDF::force_ascii the method performing those top 4 lines?

Answer (score 0):

```
date_node = div.xpath('.//p[@class="author"]').first
```

if div.xpath('.//p[@class="author"]') is empty, date_node is nil.

```
date = SDF::force_ascii(date_node.content.chomp.strip.reverse[0..17].reverse) if date_node
# that hurted
date = SDF:::force_ascii(date_node.content.strip[-17, 17])
```

if date_node is nil, the date=SDF::force_ascii(date_node.content.chomp.strip.reverse[0..17].reverse) will not be executed.